# what does it mean to use DEFINE_string

Tags: c++, flags, mediapipe

```
DEFINE_string(
    calculator_graph_config_file, "",
    "Name of file containing text format CalculatorGraphConfig proto.");
```

This is part of a code offered by Google's mediapipe for image recognition can someone tell me what this (DEFINE_string) does?

Comment: DEFINE_string is either the name of a function or of a preprocessor macro.  If it is the same code, https://gflags.github.io/gflags/ implies that it is a macro.  It looks like this is the source: https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/src/gflags.h.in

Answer (score 3):

That is just a function to define flags... a macro function more specifically and is described in the doc [here](https://gflags.github.io/gflags/#define):

> Defining a flag is easy: just use the appropriate macro for the type you want the flag to be, as defined at the bottom of gflags/gflags.h. Here's an example file, foo.cc:

so you can not just define string flags, you could also

```
DEFINE_bool: boolean
DEFINE_int32: 32-bit integer
DEFINE_int64: 64-bit integer
DEFINE_uint64: unsigned 64-bit integer
DEFINE_double: double
```